# Open specific app overlay permission setting (Android 11)

Tags: android, settings, android-permissions

I'm using this snippet to open the overlay-permission settings page of my app:

```
startActivityForResult(
    Intent(
        Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
        Uri.parse("package:$packageName")
    ),
    REQUEST_OVERDRAW_PERMISSION_CODE
)
```

It opens my app's related setting correctly on androids below 11, but on android 11 it opens the general setting of the overlay-permission and doesn't open my app (and user has to look for it). Is there any solution to open a specific app's permission directly?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a behaviour change that is introduced from Android 11 (API 30) onwards

> Beginning with Android 11, `ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION` intents always bring the user to the top-level Settings screen, where the user can grant or revoke the `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permissions for apps. Any `package: data` in the intent is ignored.

Reference from official documentation:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/permissions#manage_overlay